# Binary name or application name: same thing?

Tags: iphone, ios

I hope someone can help me with my doubt.
I've done 3 different applications starting from the code of the first one, as a result I have 3 different binaries, but they all have the same name.

Is this relevant for iTunes submission or the important thing is just the name I'll give them during the submission process? Should I rename them?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names won't be an issue..but **Bundle Identifier in the info.plist is** ..

If the **Bundle identifier is different** for all three then that means 3 different apps.
If same..then they all will be 1 app.you can upload only one of these binary to iTunes Connect

Answer (score 5):

An app has at least 4 different names:

- the name you give iTunes connect (which appears in the App store),
- the bundle file name (the Product name),
- the bundle ID suffix, and
- the bundle display name (appears under the icon).

The bundle ID is the unique identifier within the App store, but the user never sees it.  But the bundle ID must absolutely be unique, both for testing on your device and for the App store.  The user also never sees the Product name unless the search around within their iTunes file directory.  The App store name must also be unique, not only for your apps, but usually within the entire App store.

These 4 names are all individually customizable between Xcode and iTunes Connect.  There are many apps approved in the App store in which all 4 of these names are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle display name
```

In the info.plist is the name shown under the icon when app is installed.

```
Product Name
PRODUCT_NAME
This is the basename of the product generated. [PRODUCT_NAME]
```

Comment: I mean, can I submit 3 applications that have the same binary name and give them a different one when I submit them or I have to change their name before the submission?

Comment: You will have to change the bundle IDs to all be unique, or else you will only be able to submit one of them.